# Random walk with cyclic randomness

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-walks

Let $S=\{0,1\}^n$ be a binary string of length $n$. Suppose you pick a number $r$ at random from any distribution on $\{1,\ldots,R\}$ of your choice and randomly generate $r$ boolean hash functions $h_0, h_1,\ldots, h_{r-1}: \{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$. Using these hash functions, you take a one-directional random walk on $S$, starting at time $t=1$ and index $i=1$ so that if $h_{t \bmod{r}}(S[i])=1$, then you move from index $i$ to $i+1$. In other words, if the value of the hash function, indexed by your current time, of the character of your current position is $1$, then you move forwards in $S$. The random walk ends when you've processed the entire string $S$, i.e., when you've hit index $n+1$.

Conditioned on the random walk ending, do there exist $R=\text{polylog}(n)$ and constant $c>0$ for which we can upper bound the probability that the random walk ends at time $t\equiv 0 \bmod{r}$ by at most $O\left(\frac{1}{R^c}\right)$? Note that for $R=O(1)$, the probability is bounded by $\frac{1}{2}$ depending on the realization of $h_{r-1}$ and for $R=\Omega(n)$ with sufficiently large constant, the probability is bounded by $O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ from anti-concentration.

Comment: Should the hash domain be larger than $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: No, the input to the hash functions is the symbol of the binary string $S$ at the current time/position, so I think $\{0,1\}$ is fine.

Comment: ok, fine, the term "hash" is misleading though, it is usually associated with a length compressing string function. You may have said that you added a random noise bit $\pmod 2$ to the $S[i].$

Comment: I think you misstated something. What's to stop us from taking large $R$, but always taking $r=1$ (since we are allowed to have it be taken from any probability distribution on $\{1,\ldots,R\}$)?

Comment: Yeah you're right, for $r=1$, it may be possible that $h_0(0)=h_1(0)=0$, so that the random walk never progresses (and in general), so I should have asked whether we can upper bound the probability, conditioned on the random walk terminating. Thanks for bringing it up, I've corrected the question.

Note that for $h_0(0)=h_0(1)=1$, the random walk always terminates at some time congruent to $0\pmod{1}=0\pmod{r}$, so we cannot upper bound the probability by $\frac{1}{R^c}$.

Comment: Yea, you can’t upperbound by any function of $R$ alone (e.g., the support could be much smaller than $R$).  You should *maybe* say something about the entropy of the distribution...?  I can imagine a bound like that coming in.

Comment: Not sure I understand; we get to pick the distribution on $R$, so if we get a distribution for which we cannot upper bound the probability by any function of $R$ alone, doesn't that just mean we picked a bad distribution?